# Is this PHP code has some worth?

Tags: php, reference

I found this in a library and wonder if it has some worth doing it? and why referencing with true and false?

```
$return = true;

if(/* Something went success */)
{
    $return &= true;
}
else
{
    $return &= false;
}

return $return;
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Why referencing with true and false?

Comment: It in the question, does this code has any worth?

Comment: There's very little worth other than making it less readable.

Comment: `if(/* Something didn't go success */) { $return = false; }` or even `return (bool)/* Something went success */;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in the given example it does not make sense to use binary anding.

In a broader scenario this would indeed make sense.

Let's assume you have multiple steps that may result true or false which form some sort of process:

```
$return = true;

$return = step1();
$return = step2();
return $return;
```

The process has failed when `step1` or `step2` has failed.

When `step1` returns false, then your process has failed but you still perform `step2`
However if step2() returns true, then suddenly your entire process will return true even if a step before has failed.

By binary and-ing results you ensure that once failed `$return` will remain failed as

```
true & true = true
true & false = false
false & false = false
```

e.g.

```
$return = true;

$return &= step1();
$return &= step2();
return $return;
```

This is not uncommon in scenarios were a set of validators is applied to data and it is desired that if one validator has failed to keep going without exiting early. Might be of use to indicate what validator has failed, etc.

Comment: Well Thank you! I got the explanation, but its not worth doing it I guess. Its just complex the code. And you will be keep debugging it where $return modified.

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir your code above not, no. But I was not sure whether this is some sort of simplified version of a more complex scenario. If not, then no.

Comment: I mean why complex the code if it has no worth!

Comment: It can become less complex and even better maintainable (than the verbose version) if and when there are multiple conditions and states. Programmers can "hold" only so many different states at a time in their mind. Then it's absolutely worth it to draw a litte Karnaugh-Veitch map and reduce the states.

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir And I guess the above comment explains it better than I ever could've.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $return &= true;
```

is same as

```
 $return = $return & true;
```

---

```
true & true   // 1
false & true  // 0
true & false  // 0
false & false //0
```

The code is actually want to do something like:

If `Something went success`, then return `true` if `$return` is true, return `false` if `$return` is `false`.

Else, no matter whether `$return` is, return `false`.

But it return `0/1` instead of `true/false`.

If you want to return actually `true/false`, you have to do:

```
if($condition_of_something)
{
    $return = $return && true;
}
else
{
    $return = false;
}

return $return;
```

And you could simplify the code to:

```
return $return && $condition_of_something;
```

Comment: Yes, it is. But _is that code has some worth_ ? (I mean, while this is correct, I doubt this is an answer because original question isn't clear at all)

Comment: Why would I return like this "$return & true"

Comment: @AlmaDo See my edit, made some explanation.

Comment: Well, if you're about dv - then it wasn't from me. I just don't understand how is it possible to answer OP's question without additional clarifications